# insert multiple rows using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What's wrong with this code? i want to insert multiple rows with same movie id and different actor id. when i run this with $actors = array(1,2,3,4); (or any value) and $movid = 1, all the four rows are inserted as values (1, 4).

```
$create_query = "INSERT INTO `tableName`(`movId`, `actId`) VALUES";
$comma = "";
foreach ($actors as $key=>$value) {
    $create_query .= $comma . "(:movie" . $key . ", :actor" . $key . ")";
    $comma = ", ";
}
$query = $db->prepare($create_query);
foreach ($actors as $key=>$value) {
    echo $movid . ', ' . $value //correct output (1, 1), (1, 2) ...
    $query->bindParam(":movie" . $key, $movid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(":actor" . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
print_r($query);
//output is
/*INSERT INTO `tableName`(`movId`, `actId`) VALUES(:movie0, :actor0), (:movie1, :actor1), (:movie2, :actor2), (:movie3, :actor3)*/
if ($query->execute()) {
    $return = $query->rowCount();
    $query->closeCursor();
}
```

when i use separate queries for inserting, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of `PDOStatement::bindParam()`.  The latter will bind *by reference*, and since you're using a variable that changes with each loop iteration, you end up trying to bind everything to the same thing.

From the [documentation for `PDOStatement::bindParam()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

Comment: that's not me... anyway, thanks. but i could not figure out the error

Comment: @user1257030: I explained the error.  Use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`.  Unless you have some other problem, this will fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much... Your answer was right.

The conclusion i reached is use $actors[$key] instead of $value in the second foeach

This runs correctly...

Comment: @user1257030: You can use `$value` just fine if you do what I suggested.  For example: `$query->bindValue(':actor' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT)`.  There is no need to use `$actors[$key]`.

Comment: In that way, i have to use the execute() within foreach. Then it will be executed many times

Comment: @user1257030: No you don't.  You can leave your code just how it was and change nothing except use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()` and it will work.  Did you even try it?